# How to find out what biological effects a molecule has, without having a specific mechanism or pathway in mind?

Tags: assay-development, proteomics, metabolomics, high-throughput

I'm interested in finding what biological effects a (small) molecule has in a high-throughput and "low-assumption" way. I'm mainly interested in cell-based assays.

Background: There are easy/fast assays of high level phenotype effects eg cell proliferation or differentiation, but those wouldn't pick up lots of molecules as being active at all, unless they're at toxic levels. There are also a lot of assays which look at a specific pathway, eg using a Western blot with an antibody to a phosphorylated protein (phospho-Akt comes to mind). But those don't help if one doesn't already know the relevant pathways; they're more useful if screening molecules that target a known pathway, or confirming a known/suspected mechanism of action (and also most really aren't high throughput).

I'm interested in assays which can produce information on *everything* a molecule does when interacting with a cell, if possible in a single experiment.

Some things that come to mind:

- Gene expression profiling (eg using microarrays or RNAseq): gives information on the expression of everything; it is comprehensive and reasonably high throughput. The main limitation is that expression is usually a few steps downstream of what the molecule would interact with, unless it is literally interacting with transcription factors; so it would usually require tracing changes back up various signalling pathways
- Proteomics (eg 2D-PAGE, shotgun proteomics): gives information on protein abundance, and potentially post-translational modifications. Seems hard; for 2D-PAGE for example typically a couple of thousands of spots can be identified (a fraction of the whole proteome), and the amount of protein in each measured to within ~20% accuracy (semi-quantitative). Possibly also needs a fairly large sample
- Metabolomics (eg LCMS): gives information on all metabolites

Are there any other types of assays that would give information across all/many genes/proteins/enzymes/signalling pathways?

Comment: Okay, I cleared up the comments here including my own. You're right, they're unfriendly. But, on the other hand, your question is pretty rude, too. You're asking for a shortcut to knowing everything, seemingly without having done any work yet yourself. It does sound like you're looking for something very similar to a company recently in the news as a scam. Why do you think there is some magic secret method you can learn by asking a single question on Stack Exchange while everyone else in biology is working hard on other methods? Do you think they're just wasting their time and money?

Comment: You're also dismissing techniques that other people put a ton of effort into developing because they're "too hard". Science isn't easy. Everything easy is already done, hard is all that is left. If it's easy, it's not valuable.

Comment: @BryanKrause I'm sorry it came off that way. I am actually very familiar with the opposite problem: given a target protein/pathway, find small molecules/peptides/proteins that interact with it. It seems most biochemical and cell based assays are optimized for that, while finding all things that a specific single small molecule interacts with is a much less common type of screen. Possibly it's just my unfamiliarity with that type of workflow, but the answer is highly non-obvious. I don't expect a secret method, and I'm not dismissing methods which are hard, just noting that

Answer (score 5):

Personally I think this is a poor question, because the answer is immediately obvious to anyone who was worked with current technologies for both proteins and nucleic acids, but as always, it is hard to prove a negative.

The short answer is NO, not even close to a single experiment or assay that can tell us EVERYTHING  a single protein can do/interact with. If there were, we would be in a situation where almost all of cell biology could be done in a few thousand experiments.

Let's take a well known protein that people have been studying for quite some time now - the "Guardian of the Genome", [Tumour Protein p53](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene?cmd=search&term=7157) (TP53, AKA p53). This is admittedly an integral protein to cellular function, so has a lot of interactions - but it serves to illustrate the point.

Now, let's head to the [STRING database for this protein](https://string-db.org/network/9606.ENSP00000269305). STRING is a database that charts protein-protein interactions through a number of sources, mostly from the literature, but also through predicted interactions, with varying levels of confidence. Check out the legend and settings tabs for the page to see how those work.

The initial page for p53 should show you p53 and 10 other interacting proteins - these are the most highly significant interactions, with the greatest confidence in them being real. Now, click on the "+More" tab, and you should see 20 interactions - do this a few more times and watch that number and the complexity of interactions grow - it'll show interactions, not just with p53 but between other displayed proteins too. This is a fairly simplistic way to show the number of interactions a single protein has inside the cell. You should finally come up with a few hundred different proteins that have been found to interact with p53. Now, don't forget these are protein-protein interactions only.

p53 is also a DNA binding protein - it is predicted to interact with the genome at about 55,000 binding sites (see sect 2.1, para 2 in [this publication](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6888028/)) - What does it do at each of those sites? Short answer is - we don't know. Maybe upregulates something, maybe downregulates, maybe nothing, maybe something else.

There's also some evidence that [p53 interacts with various types of RNA molecules](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6314037/), some of which are only relatively recently discovered, so assays for them are still fairly primitive. Again, what it does there, we don't know.

If you have ever worked with proteins and DNA, you will know that the methods of working with each are usually quite distinct - which also puts a technological barrier to your idea of a single unified assay. Of course, it is entirely possible to do DNA or RNA-protein interaction studies (e.g. ChIP), but to do these at the same time as protein-protein in a single assay - no chance.

There's also a second (third?) problem - sensitivity. Currently, with most technologies, you can have it one of two ways, but generally not both! You can either detect the rare interactions - the 1 in 1,000,000, by removing the common ones; or you can see the common ones but not the rare, because the common ones swamp the rare. An example of this is in RNA sequencing. In a cell, [ribosomal RNAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosomal_RNA) (rRNA) make up about 80% of cellular RNA, despite not coding for proteins (that I know of). So, if you want to look at a cellular coding RNA by next-gen sequencing, most of the time you will do a rRNA depletion or else 80% of the raw signals will be rRNA, which is a waste of your useful information achievable.

Edited to add:

As has been clarified in comments, OP is not asking for a single assay to do all, but rather types of assays that might be suitable to produce similar results - basically things like Next Gen sequencing, but for small-molecule (not necessarily protein-protein) interactions, which essentially turns this into a shopping question, which are generally not considered appropriate for this site as tools/techniques change quite frequently. It might be more appropriate on bioinformatics.

As always, the content I wrote above applies, particularly the bits about sensitivity and technological barriers.

As far as I know, no such assays exist for proteins, but the one that might come the closest is [protein mass spectrometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_mass_spectrometry) by MALDI-ToF with *de-novo* peptide sequencing. These are (in my very limited experience with them) by no means as trivial as setting up a Next Gen sequencing run, but I am sure the technology and associated bioinformatics tools will improve and mature over the next few years.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I'm sorry you think it's a poor question, let me know how it can be improved.  I'm looking mainly for a way to find what external treatments interact with; small molecules which act on surface receptors or diffuse inside the cell, rather than interactions of proteins already in the cell. STING is a cool database! I looked at the type of experiments used to build it, a lot of it is either co-immunoprecipitation or affinity chromatography. These are specific to PPI, again very cool but don't work for the small molecule scenario

Comment: "a single unified assay" - I mean a single assay per type of result, not single unified assay for everything, of course. For example all proteins a small molecule binds to, or all changes in phosphorylation due to treatment with a small molecule. Roughly in the way that RNA-Seq gives information on all RNA, whereas RT-qPCR only looks at one or a few selected ones.

Comment: @AlexI so *I'm interested in assays which can produce information on everything a molecule does when interacting with a cell, if possible in a single experiment.* doesn't mean a single assay - 'cause that's sure what it reads like to me. You've improved the question, but the complexity of the problem still stands. PPI like with p53 is a single example. Yes, there are mass methods - next gen sequencing is great for genomic and RNA effects, but nothing even remotely similar exists in the protein world that I am aware of.

Comment: @AlexI - I also read your question as one assay to determine *everything*, etc. which, I confess, was the reason for my downvote. That is in reality a preposterous request. If you actually meant something different, it didn't read that way.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yeah, what I meant was one molecule x a view across all targets/pathways/etc, rather than the more usual screen of thousands of molecules x one target. The examples hopefully clarify that, RNA-Seq is an example that works to quantify the effects on the transcription of *everything* at the same time. I was looking for methods which provide similarly comprehensive data on (eg) binding, phosphorylation, etc. Please feel free to add an answer if you can think of anything.